# vivado tcl Automatically send email after bit or synthesis is generated

Tags: email, smtp, tcl, vivado

I want vivado to automatically send an email to my mailbox after the synthesis is finished.
In the W10 environment, there are related tcl statements in the xilinx manual, but they can only be used on the remote side
Locally, I tried the following codes, but there are some errors. I wonder if anyone has succeeded?

```
package require smtp
set smtp_server "smtp.example.com"
set smtp_port 587
set smtp_user "user@example.com"
set smtp_password "password"

set subject "Vivado ok"
set message "Vivado ok"

set to "recipient@example.com"

smtp::sendmessage $smtp_server $smtp_port 
                  -username $smtp_user -password $smtp_password 
                  -headers [list Subject $subject To $to] 
                  -body $message
```

Vivado says：Each option must have a value!  Invalid option list: 587

（I use outlook email， its smtp port is 587）

Can someone tell me where the tcl code is wrong or other ways to realize the function of automatically sending emails at the end of vivado synthesis?

Comment: It seems that -header option value only takes a list of 2 elements. But you can have multiple -header options in a single command.

Comment: thank you，however，an error is reported after entering the line "smtp::sendmessage $smtp_server $smtp_port"

Answer (score 0):

Do you have several lines for the smtp::sendmessage call?

Does putting it in one line:

```
smtp::sendmessage $smtp_server $smtp_port -username $smtp_user -password $smtp_password -headers [list Subject $subject To $to] -body $message
```

or using newline substitution at line end:

```
smtp::sendmessage $smtp_server $smtp_port \
                  -username $smtp_user -password $smtp_password \
                  -headers [list Subject $subject To $to] \
                  -body $message
```

help?

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but I have some problems with my PC environment, because I seem to have broken my environment by installing the tcllib library before, and now I need to fix that before I can test it. I will communicate with you as soon as I have new test results

Comment: I tested both codes on another computer with vivado2021.2 and was prompted with the message Each option must have a value!
Also I searched for another line of code:
```
smtp::sendmessage $smtp_server -port 587 -username $smtp_user -password $smtp_password -headers [list Subject $subject To $to] -body $message,
```
after using it, also reported an error, prompting unknown option -port

Comment: try '-ports' instead of '-port' see: https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/mime/smtp.md

Comment: and maybe skip "everything that is not absolutely necessary" for testing (until you get an error free call of sendmessage proc. Then add what is needed to send the mail.
E.g. -headers -- strip it for testing.
Documentation states:
-header
A list containing two elements, an smtp header and its associated value (the -header option may occur zero or more times).
so maybe you could add -header [list To $to] -header [list Subject $subject] later on ...

Comment: Now I had another look at the smtp documentation linked above - I think you need to use the mime package to generate a 'token' - refer to the example (send_simple_message) in the documentation